# How to play twitch.tv live streaming video with native control in iOS?

Tags: ios, live-streaming, twitch, twitch-api

I like to play twitch.tv live streaming videos into my mobile application. currently I am playing with webview and iFrame.

Is there any way to play the live steam with native controls like AVPlayer.

Comment: I have removed the asking for an SDK from the title of your question as asking for off-site resources such as SDK's, API's etc is off-topic and your question would be closed. Provide the code you are using already, have you tried to load a video using an AVPlayerController? doesn't the API provide a video url you can load into AVPlayer?

Comment: Not directly from what I've seen.  There might be some equivalent of Livestreamer/Streamlink for IOS, but for now they're just for windows and *nix.  It does sound possible to do with an intermediary device.  See: https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink/issues/1434